# R: Launch web browser

Tags: r

Is there a way to launch internet explorer with a given URL in R?  I want to scrape web pages in order to extract certain values, but I want to open the web pages themselves just so I can step through each one to make sure the data seems right.

Comment: It should be noted that opening a browser from R will do exactly just that; it will not provide a way for R to communicate or control it. Users looking to use R for webscraping should consider using the `RSelenium` package, as it provides a number of functions to navigate and interact with web pages.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here you go:

```r
browseURL("https://www.r-project.org")
```

If you need it, `browseURL()` also takes an argument `browser=` that lets you specify the name or path of the program to be used as a browser.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like:

```
system("iexplore.exe http://www.foo.bar/eggs.html")
```

Could work under windows.